# monodroid sample compile problem

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to use OpenGL with Monodroid, but by using get Unhandled Exception *not only in my personal project*, but also in the **sample project GLTriangle20**.
Seems that something wrong with installed stuff, I think.

By reading README file of available samples  I read:

In order to build, the following must be installed first:

- **Android SDK, containing at least API level 7 (Android 2.1)**
- **Java SDK**
- **MonoDroid SDK**

I have not only **Android SDK 7 for Android 2.1** but also 
**Android SDK 8, revision 2 for android 2.2** and also 
**Android SDK 9, revision 1 for Android 2.3.**

Can be this is the problem , so I need uninstall them and use exclusively that one specified in README file?

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Can you post the details of your Unhandled Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I find out the problem. 
Unhandled not supported exception, was thrown due the not correct refactoring of renaming of  dirived classes from Action  and View..